# How to generate objects with complex condition in a functional manner?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I want to create a list of Java objects based on some conditions.  I want to do this using functional programming principles.

I took a look at Stream.generate() with .limit() but I can't add a predicate to limit to stop with a condition.  Plus I don't know how to pass the modified start OffSetDateTime to the new object to be created.

```java
public class Test {

    private String name;
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

}
```

```java
    public List<Test> generateTestObjects(OffsetDateTime startTime) {

        ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
        for(OffsetDateTime start = startTime; start.isBefore(startTime.plusMinutes(100)); start = start.plusMinutes(1)) {
            tests.add(new Test(start));
        }

        return tests;

    }
```

Comment: can use ```takeWhile``` to pass a predicate to stop the stream, but you need Java 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 9, you can use the three-argument [`Stream#iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) with the condition that you already have in your for-loop:

```
public Stream<OffsetDateTime> generateTestObjects(OffsetDateTime startTime) {
    return Stream.iterate(startTime, time -> time.isBefore(startTime.plusMinutes(100)), 
            time -> time.plusMinutes(1));
}
```

If you want to return a `List`, you can add `.collect(Collectors.toList())`:

```
public List<OffsetDateTime> generateTestObjects(OffsetDateTime startTime) {
    return Stream.iterate(startTime, time -> time.isBefore(startTime.plusMinutes(100)), 
            time -> time.plusMinutes(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that I excluded your mapping to `Test`, which would be equivalent to adding `.map(Test::new)` before calling `collect`.